# Order of answers is random when ordered by vote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When I refresh the page of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205569/dont-log-certain-requests-in-apache-access-log), the order of the answers changes randomly (I use order by vote). This is a self answer question (I don't know if it's important for ordering).

Comment: The answers have the same number of votes.

Comment: It's an unstable sort and I found it mildly irritating. But, I presume its by design intended use makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you see the score of both answers?

It is the same.

The answer marked as accepted is a self answer, self accepted, so it doesn't get pinned to the top, as you would usually expect.

So the order is randomized between the answers to ensure that one doesn't get more views than the others (and help with *fairness* when voting).

Comment: But one of those is marked as answer

Comment: And sometimes, the answers that the OP has marked as the one that helped them most is not the best answer.

Comment: Ok but the one marked as answer is more likely to help future user imo

Comment: @TimB because it's an accepted *self*-answer, it isn't shown at the top.

Comment: @TimB To clarify what Oded means: accepted answers posted by the asker of the question are not automatically pinned at the top, but instead sorted as if they are not accepted.

Comment: Ok I didnt know that, thanks !

Comment: @TimB "Ok but the one marked as answer is more likely to help future user imo"* - The person who sets that check is the person who asked the question - the one who didn't know/understand. Only *one* potentially uninformed person gets to decide what gets marked. Is that really such a valuable indicator? I don't have full faith in votes either, but I still value votes a whole lot more than the accepted mark.

Comment: @Gimby Sure votes are way more important than accepted mark, but we are talking about vote equality here. If the OP marks his own answer, it means it works at least for him, which is better than nothing